# Failed to convert String to timestamp in athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I tried to parsed String to timestamp in athena but it's Failed.

```
cast(date_parse("2020-12-17 15:26:55.138000011", '%Y %M %d %T:%f') as timestamp)
```

The Error:

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2020-12-17 15:26:55.138000011" is malformed at "-12-17 15:26:55.138000011"

I tried different formats:

`'%y %M %d %T:%f'` - changed to "20-12-17 15:26:55.138000011".

I want the full year

Answer (score 0):

You got your delimiters wrong (and some format specifiers):

1. You have `-` as date delimiters in the source, but using spaces in the format
2. dot (`.`) is delimiter between the fraction of second and the rest of time
3. `%M` is *"Month name (January .. December)"* ([docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions)), use `%m` - *"Month, numeric (01 .. 12) 4"*.

Also `timestamp` already returns `timestamp`, no cast needed. So try:

```sql
select date_parse('2020-12-17 15:26:55.138000011', '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f');
```

Output:

```
          _col0          
-------------------------
 2020-12-17 15:26:55.138
```